# Linux - Rename all folders to upper in a destination

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, directory, rename

I got a folder (lets say it's name is `../TEMPO`) with many folders inside [A,B,C..Z] on a linux machine.
Each folder has 3 more levels of folders. Some of the deeper folders are with lowercase name, Example:

```
A/F/m/O
Z/t/q/S
```

In the 4th level there are files which i would like to keep with the same name as it is now.

How can I rename just the folders name to uppercase recursively without changing the files name exists in a specific folder (`../TEMPO`)?

Comment: You tagged this Linux, not Windows, so I have taken the liberty of making your slashes go the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify the output of this command

```
find path/to/dir -type d | awk -F"/" '$NF != toupper($NF) {l = n = $0; sub($NF "$", toupper($NF), n); print "mv " l " " n;}' | tac
```

and if it looks fine, execute the results by piping the results to sh

```
find path/to/dir -type d | awk -F"/" '$NF != toupper($NF) {l = n = $0; sub($NF "$", toupper($NF), n); print "mv " l " " n;}' | tac | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
for dir in `find ./TEMPO -type d -regex '.*[a-z].*' -print` ; do
    udir=`echo $dir | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`
    mv $dir $udir
done
```

Comment: I think this will try to make multiple changes in one 'mv' operation, which won't work.

Comment: With bash, you can write `udir=${dir^^}` and not have to call echo and tr

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this one directory level at a time, because the underlying [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) system call can only make one change at a time.

The tool to reach for is the `rename` utility that comes with Perl; I can't find its documentation on the web, or I'd link to it.  If typing `man rename` at the shell prompt brings up something like this:

```
NAME
       rename - renames multiple files

SYNOPSIS
       rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
```

then you have the right thing.  Unfortunately, there is at least one other utility with the same name that is more-or-less useless for this job, and the only way to tell which you have is to try it.

Since you know you have four directory levels with one-character names, you can just enumerate the directory levels, like so:

```
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/ if -d $_' ?
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/ if -d $_' ?/?
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/ if -d $_' ?/?/?
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/ if -d $_' ?/?/?/?
```

If there could be arbitrary nesting, you would have to be cleverer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `prename`, which is part of `perl`, you can do this very easily:

```
find ../TEMPO -depth -type d | xargs prename 's%/([^/]+)$%/\U$1%'
```

You may want to pass `-n` to `prename` first, to verify it will do the right thing.